# Why does my API return "You are not subscribed to this APi" even with the X-RapidAPI-Key?

Tags: reactjs, rapidapi

The link to my rapidAPI is below

https://rapidapi.com/ytdlfree/api/youtube-v31?utm_source=youtube.com%2FJavaScriptMastery

This is my RAPID API code:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = 'https://youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com';

const options = {
  params: {
    maxResults: '50'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

export const fetchFromAPI = async(url) =>{
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${url}`, options);

    return data;

}
```

This is for fetching the data:

```
import { fetchFromAPI } from '../utils/fetchFromAPI';

const Feed = () => {

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('New');
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

    useEffect (() =>{
      fetchFromAPI(`search?part=snippet&q=${selectedCategory}`)
      .then((data) => setVideos(data.items))
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response) {
          // Request made but the server responded with an error
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
          // Request made but no response is received from the server.
          console.log(error.request);
        } else {
          // Error occured while setting up the request
          console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
    });
```

I saved my API key to the `.env` file at the root directory of this application but it kept showing message:

> You are not subscribed to this API
> [[Prototype]]
>
> Object

How can I solve this?

Comment: It is working fine on my end. Have you tried looking into the request object to see whether you are properly sending the key or not?

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to subscribe API key..

**Second** , use env variable like this ..

```
**REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY = '9fbc4844e8msfdf8absdzgd3ffp182459jsdfdsf909d079cdds'**
```

don't put semicolon or anything at the end of env variable like this ..

```
REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY = '9fbc4844e8msfdf8absdzgd3ffp182459jsdfdsf909d079cdds';
```

Also , try to log the env variable in the console like ..

console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY);

try to restart the server after changing env file ...

```
yarn start / npm start
```

Comment: I mistakenly added semicolon to the end of the rapidAPI key

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem following JSM Youtube_Clone Project.
The solution to that is extracting key from the custom config file rather than .env :

1. Create a file config.js and store the key in here rather than as an environment variable.

```js
//config.js file

export const REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY = " *your_key_here* ";
```

2. Retrieve the key from config and import where ever it's needed.

```js
import { REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY } from "./config";
```

and use it in "options" fucntion's -> headers as :

```js
'X-RapidAPI-Key': REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
```

However, it's a temporary solution to keep going with the project (because the Api_key is not protected) and process.env.Key is not working in this case. I could'nt find "the why".